# Pandas resample OHLC

Tags: python, pandas

I have data like this

```
                             bid
time                             
2016-05-22 21:05:57.651  18.32280
2016-05-22 21:06:58.005  18.32280
2016-05-22 21:17:30.739  18.31820
2016-05-22 21:17:34.121  18.31820
...
```

When I try to

```
df_ohlcMXN = dfmxn.resample('5Min').ohlc()
```

I get an error

```
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means your `bid` isn't the right datatype.

When you do `dfmxn.dtypes`, if you see `object` for the `Bid`, it needs to be converted like this:

```
dfmxn['Bid'] = dfmxn['Bid'].astype('float64')
dfmxn.resample('5Min').ohlc()
```

Produced this for me:

```
                         Bid                           
                        open     high      low    close
Time                                                   
2016-05-22 21:05:00  18.3228  18.3228  18.3228  18.3228
2016-05-22 21:10:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2016-05-22 21:15:00  18.3182  18.3182  18.3182  18.3182
```